# Google maps API kml overlay sections not showing in Chrome unless I go all the way around the world

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a map over which I place KML overlays from a couple of weather sources. I also show the API weather clouds and local forecasts.

It works pretty well, except for one weird problem. When using Chrome, and I originally call up the map, I see the map and the clouds, but not the local forecasts and KML overlays. There appears to be a section of the overlays missing. If I pan *all the way around the world* by dragging the map to the right, and come back to my original location, I see everything.

History has been cleared and settings checked. Just not getting that one section of data to be displayed in Chrome, unless I pan around.

It all seems to work fine on Firefox (I'm a Linux user, so no IE testing at the moment).

Here's the page:

http://www.vallartayachtclub.org/weather-and-tides/842-storm-track-and-general-weather-2

Code is here:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;libraries=weather">          </script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.693307,-112.293924);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlng,
    panControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
    }
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://my.sfwmd.gov/sfwmd/common/images/weather/plots/storm_all.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
});
kmlLayer.setMap(map);

var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/kml/nhc_active.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
});
kmlLayer.setMap(map);

var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
cloudLayer.setMap(map);

var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
    temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
});
weatherLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script><table align="center" width="600px">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                This is a custom map created specifically for VYC. It can take up to a minute to load.</div>
            <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 700px; z-index: 51; position: relative; top: -20px;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Explanation and copyright here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your javascript works fine in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: Btw, the Weather library has been deprecated and will stop working in June 2015. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/weatherlayer

Comment: Darn. Thanks for that. I guess I'll have to find yet another KML overlay.